# an array of automatic storage class in C is not put in the stack by the compiler

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, stack, allocation

The TASKING compiler shows different output related to the initialisation of automatic array within a function for an embedded project:

Code Variant 1:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH (3u)

void my_func(void)
{
    /* VARIANT 1: Initialisation of array */
    float my_array[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {1.f,2.f,3.f};

    ...

    return;
}
```

Code Variant 2:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH (3u)

void my_func(void)
{
    /* VARIANT 2: array is not initialized */
    float my_array[ARRAY_LENGTH];

    /* VARIANT 2: values are assigned later in the code */
    my_array[0] = 1.f;
    my_array[1] = 2.f;
    my_array[2] = 3.f;

    ...

    return;
}
```

By generating a .map file using Code Variant 1, I can observe that compiler allocates some place in a data memory for this local array.

In contrast, I don't observe it by Code Variant 2, presuming that the compiler puts the local array in the stack.

For the moment I could not find the explanation in the TASKING User Manual

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show us the map files, and add comments on the lines where you think you make your observations.

Comment: the map file cannot be posted being very project specific

Comment: There's nothing in the C standard forcing it to allocate things on the stack. In fact why would you even want this variable to be on the stack? Are the values to be changed in run-time? What is the target CPU? Does it have a FPU?

Comment: The AURIX chip has FPU, yes.  As chip data memory section is partitioned according to the application needs, I don't want any arbitrary allocations and desired behaviour to put it in the allocated stack section

Comment: My guess would be that it's better for performance to put the initialized data in a data segment, so that it's already set up when the code starts running, instead of having to put the equivalent assignment code in the function.

Comment: A possibility is that, with `float my_array[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {1.f,2.f,3.f};`, the compiler initializes the array by putting the initial values in a data section and, when the function executes, copies them into stack space for the array, whereas, with the assignments, it generates instructions for the assignments, with the values as immediate operands. You need to show more information, including the generated assembly for each piece of code and the details of what the compiler puts in “a data memory.”

Answer (score -1):

Basically:

- An array at local scope has automatic storage duration and the compiler is free to allocate it where it pleases.
- An array at file scope has static storage duration and in this case it will almost certainly end up in `.data`.

So if you *want* the array to end up in `.data` then declare it `static` and/or put it at file scope.

---

Unrelated to your question, `return ;` at the end of a function returning `void` is very fishy and will not pass any decent safety-related code review. Because weird code added at a whim with no rationale behind it is unacceptable in safety-related applications (and likely also a MISRA violation, off the top of my head).

Comment: (Notably though, these AURIX parts used are safety microcontrollers. It is custom for safety/automotive applications _not_ to rely on static storage default initialization of values, since the time between initialization and use of such variables could be anything. Best practice is to initialize them just before use. Meaning that depending on your requirements, you may want them to end up in `.bss` and not `.data`. This used to be a much bigger deal in the past than it is nowadays though, since RAM is much more reliable these days and you will probably even have hardware ECC.)

Comment: yes I agree on this point, static storage is not typical in my projects. Particulary in safety applications the variable initialisation shall be very deterministic.  That is why I don't want to declare them static within function. The solution might be to declare them static within file scope basicaly with internal linkage.  But still I cannot explain the different compiler outputs for varinat 1 and varinat 2.  I can only join unwind  guess that it might be due to the optimisation  reasons

Comment: @AlexArpenteur Yes like I said in the answer, you can't assume that it gets allocated on the stack. In this case putting it in `.data` gives much faster code than loading it onto the stack from flash later on in run-time. Particularly so if this part has data cache.

Comment: As for the `return` topic, this piece of code is only for example purpose. However  your reasoning that a function shall return at least a status of its execution, it what you have meant ?